# Why does http.Get result in two requests instead of one?

Tags: http, testing, go, server

Create a test file `./bower_components/index.html` and run `go test` in `./`.

Why does the following print two lines instead of just the first one?

```
./bower_components/index.html                                                  
./bower_components/
```

Output:

```
=== RUN   TestRootHandler                                                      
./bower_components/index.html                                                  
./bower_components/             ???                                            
--- PASS: TestRootHandler (0.00s)                                              
        main_test.go:32: 200 - ./bower_components/Hello World.html             
PASS                                                                           
ok
```

Code:

```
// RootHandler for HTTP
func RootHandler(root string, h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, err := os.Open(root + r.URL.Path)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }
        fmt.Println(root + r.URL.Path)
        r.URL.Path = root + r.URL.Path
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

// TestRootHandler
func TestRootHandler(t *testing.T) {
    ts := httptest.NewServer(RootHandler("./bower_components", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./"))))
    defer ts.Close()
    res, err := http.Get(ts.URL + "/index.html")
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
    res.Body.Close()
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatal(err)
    }
    t.Logf("%d - %s", res.StatusCode, body)
}
```

Let me know if you don't understand the question then I will setup a github repository so you can just run the go test command to see what I mean.

Comment: But requesting favicon by http.Get doesn't make sense right?

Comment: Sorry. Missed it was executed during `go test`.

Comment: Ok no problem, ps somebody marked this as off topic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's just the way how [`http.FileServer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) is written. Quoting from its doc:

> As a special case, the returned file server redirects any request ending in "/index.html" to the same path, without the final "index.html".

This is what you experience: you were requesting `/bower_components/index.html`, so the handler returned by `http.FileServer()` sends a redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: ./
```

And [`http.Get()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Get) being well-behaved, follows this redirect, and performs another `HTTP GET`, now without the `index.html`, and the `http.FileServer()` handler will try and serve the `index.html` in such case.